# Extract Word creation date into filename

Tags: microsoft-word

I've got some Word documents with varying creation dates (both `doc` and `docx`). I would like to rename the files to include this creation date. Is this possible? This is not the filesystem *last-modified* date, this is the internal Word creation date viewable at `File->Info->Properties` inside Word

E.g. I would like to rename the document `Summary meeting 123.doc` to `123 2010-01-01 Summary meeting 123`. The 123 part is doable with a simple regex, but how can I get the file creation date?

Another solution would be to set the filesystem last-modified date to the internal word creation date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this PowerShell-script:
(found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/08/02/use-powershell-to-find-specific-word-built-in-properties.aspx)

**Edit2: Edited the script to match your specific scenario.**

```
Param(
    $path = "Q:\Test",  
    [array]$include = @("*.docx","*.docx")
)

$application = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$application.Visible = $false
$binding = "System.Reflection.BindingFlags" -as [type]
[ref]$SaveOption = "microsoft.office.interop.word.WdSaveOptions" -as [type]

## Get documents
    $docs = Get-childitem -path $Path -Recurse -Include $include    #Remove -Recurse if you dont want to include subfolders.

## Iterate documents
foreach($doc in $docs)
{
    try 
    {
        ## Get document properties:
            $document = $application.documents.open($doc.fullname)
            $BuiltinProperties = $document.BuiltInDocumentProperties
            $pn = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("item",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$BuiltinProperties,"Creation Date") 
            $value = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$pn,$null)

        ## Clean up
            $document.close([ref]$saveOption::wdDoNotSaveChanges) 
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($BuiltinProperties) | Out-Null
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($document) | Out-Null
            Remove-Variable -Name document, BuiltinProperties

        ## Rename document:
            if($doc.PSChildName -match "^(.+)(\d{3})(.+)$")  # Matches "(Summary meeting )(123)(.doc)"
            { 
                $date=$value.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd');
                $newName = "$($matches[2]) $($date) $($matches[1])$($matches[2])$($matches[3])";
                write-host $newName;
                Rename-Item $doc $newName
            }   
    }
    catch
    { 
        write-host "Rename failed."
            $_
    } 
}
## Clean up
    $application.quit()
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($application) | Out-Null
    Remove-Variable -Name application
    [gc]::collect()
    [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Change the $path-variable to whichever folder your documents are in.

Edit the #Rename section with any extra logic you need, the regex I have added matches the particular example you provided in your post, tweak it so it matches all your documents. Any pattern inside a (parentheses) can be referred to using the "matches[]" array, starting at index 1.

I would suggest commenting out the "Rename-Item" line until you're sure the "$newName" is correct. The extra $() added around the variables in the "$newName="-line is there so that the variables will expand.

***PS:*** *Make sure to enable running of powershell-scripts, open PS as admin and enter: "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned")*

Comment: Thank you, that seems suitable. I indeed can use a regex with this information, but do you know how I can use regexes in Powershell to rename files?

Comment: See updated answer.